# tkinter set widget fixed width and height

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Here i define a sub-Frame class, and want to use such frame instance in its container and set a fixed size to such widget, i tried ways like below. but always get `'MainFrame' object has no attribute 'resizable'` error. this is test demo, any help will appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

class MainFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.createWidget()

    def createWidget(self):
        self.innerFrame = Frame(self)
        self.innerFrame.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)  # ====> this place raise error:'MainFrame' object has no attribute 'resizable'
        self.innerFrame.master.maxsize(width=300, height=400)
        for l in range(100):
            label = Label(self.innerFrame, text="label" + str(l))
            label.pack()
        self.innerFrame.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    top = Tk()
    top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    top.minsize(width=400, height=600)
    app = MainFrame(top)
    app.pack()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea to force that inner frame to a fixed size.  You may end up either with a bunch of extra space, or hiding some of the internal widgets. What if you run the program on a system with a different resolution or a different default font? It's almost always a bad idea to force widgets to a specific size. Tkinter is really good at picking the right size.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know that, but the expand area will expand and cover other widgets below such frame, A better solution is add a label frame and set a scrollbar for it, but tkinter seems a little bit short on Frame widget, so i have to specify a fixed value on it temporary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.resizable()` and `.maxsize()` only apply to the Tk root window, and other windows you create with `Toplevel()`.  To make a Frame have a fixed size, give it `width=` and `height=` options when you create it, and then call either `.pack_propagate(False)` or `.grid_propagate(False)` on it (whichever one matches the geometry manager you'll be using for its child widgets).

Comment: I see, `Toplevel()` widget can only use `.pack_propagate(False)` in its create time give me hint.thank you!